# Over specification of boundary conditions on closed surfaces for Laplace's equation

Tags: electrostatics, mathematical-physics

Source - Jackson.

In one dimensional boundary value problems, one considers the  equation of type
$$D_x f(x) = g(x); \; x\in [a,b]$$ 
where f is subject to boundary conditiosn of the type
$$f(a)\alpha_1 + f'(a) \alpha_2 = 0\\f(b)\beta_1 + f'(b) \beta_2 = 0 $$

However, in 3D on closed surfaces, Jackson says either we can specify the value of the function (Dirichlet) or its normal derivative (Neumann) but not both, for it leads to over specification.

My question is, why exactly this happens? What's wrong with closed surfaces? Could we do it in 2D? Is every surface in 1D *open* in this sense?

Edit: Also, is this over specification case true only for Laplace's equation, or a whole class of equations?

Comment: Suggested addition: in particular, why is it not possible to impose Dirichlet boundary conditions on one part of a closed surface, and Neumann on the rest?

Comment: As far as I understand, this is completely doable. You can break the surface integral into two parts, to which you can separately apply the conditions.

Comment: Good point - it's just really hard to construct a Green's function that will vanish on the Dirichlet surfaces and have vanishing derivative on the Neumann ones.

Comment: Related: [well-posed problems (pde)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem).

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2626974/11127

Comment: I'm voting to close this question partly because it was crossposted.